# Show video via flash. If failed, show it via html5

Tags: flash, html

Would you please suggest how I embed a html5 video player only if there's flash in the browser? If there is flash in the browser I want to use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

*if there's NO flash in the browser (cookie turned off)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how old this article is, but it should still work:

http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/how/shock/javaplugs/javaplugs04.html

Just put your html5 code in the "Otherwise" section.